# Passing PHP sessions between Android activities

Tags: java, php, android, session

I'm developing an Android app which has its own database in a web server. My problem is when I create a log-in session in one activity, the session variables are not passed to the next activity.

I use `HttpURLConnection` to establish a connection in both activities as following. (Parameter for URL changes)

```
URL url = new URL(si_url);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

In my 2nd PHP file, `isset( $_SESSION['memberid'] )` returns **false**.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

session_start();
$value = $_SESSION['memberid'];

if(isset($_SESSION['memberid'])){
    echo (string)$_SESSION['memberid'];
}
else {
    echo "Error!";
}
?>
```

I suspect this occurs because I create 2 different connections for the 2 activities. Any solutions for this?

Comment: Open single connection inside Application object and refer to it from each Activity. You must extend Application object and point its name in android manifest file.

Comment: Kindly be more elaborate in what you are trying to achieve... if its a server session you are trying to persist within an android application then this is impossible, what you can do is use shared preferences to store `session variables` then nullify them once a user logs out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using `CookieManager`

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
try{
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
}catch(UnsupportedOperationException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just put this code somewhere in your app before it executes the `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Nice question, and nice self answer!